# Database | Google Product Feeds Field Length

Tags: database, product

Trying to construct a database to hold a bunch of product data. The plan is to programmically generate TXT (Text tab delimited) filed and upload to Google, Amazon, and Bing (all use Google Product Feeds file formatting) from the data in the database.

Problem I'm having right now is I seem to have to guess at the maximum field length for most of the available fields. I found in several places telling me what field are required/optional and what their use is for, but no where can I find how long they can be. This is critical to know in a fully automated product feed system since we don't want to pull data from our warehouse system and INSERT that into our Product Feed database if it is invalid for the Google product feeds (too long).

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

google shopping will allow up to 72 chr for the title. description fields are usually unlimited. for anything else you usually wouldn't have anything too long anyways.

There are programs out there that do this already

Comment: thanks. I'm aware plenty of programs do this already, but this is for custom integration between several proprietary warehouse systems. Unlimited seems unlikely since google has to store that data in some database field somewhere, and that field is likely to have some max on it... be it 2000 chars length or 500...